# console.log read the previous state and not the current one

Tags: react-native, state, setstate

Hi everyone i'm recently studying react native and i have a problem. After setting the status, I cannot read the current value. My code is:

```js
export default class HomePage extends Component {
    static navigation = {}
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            alreadyLaunched: null,
            sid: "aa"
        };
    }
    _getSid() {
        console.log("state value is: ", this.state.sid);
    }
    _setSid() {
        this.setState({
            sid: "bbb"
        }, function() {
            console.log(this.state.sid);
        })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("alreadyLaunched").then(value => {
            if (value == null) {
                AsyncStorage.setItem("alreadyLaunched", JSON.stringify(true));
                this.setState({
                    firstLaunch: true
                });
                this._setSid();
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    firstLaunch: false
                });
                this._getSid();
            }
        })
    }
    render() {}
}
```

My problem is that _getSid() method print "state value is aa" and not "state value is bbb". Why?

Comment: You have multiple places in your code where you are logging `sid`. Which one(s) are giving you an unexpected value?

Comment: It looks like you are writing to console before you've officially set the value.  Pull that console.log out of the setState.

Comment: My problem is that _getSid() method print "state value is aa" and not "state value is bbb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update setSid to below

```
_setSid() {
  this.setState({
    sid: "bbb"
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.sid);
  });
}
```

Ahh setSTate is async, hence getSId prints prev value, setState has a callback func.

try this

```
this.setState({
  firstLaunch: false
} ,() => {
  this._getSid();
});
```

Comment: Hi the problem is that _getSid() method print "state value is aa" and not "state value is bbb"

Comment: @Elly just updated the answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on the `ComponentDidMount` method.

```
componentDidMount() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem("alreadyLaunched").then(value => {
    if (value == null) {
      AsyncStorage.setItem("alreadyLaunched", JSON.stringify(true));
      this.setState({
        firstLaunch: true
      });
      this._setSid();
    } else {
      this.setState({
        firstLaunch: false
      });
      this._getSid();
    }
  })
}
```

Here, if `value` is null, then it updates the `sid` state variable, but otherwise, it doesn't update `sid`.
When you launch this at first time, the value is null. as a result, it goes to first clause, in this case, you can see the log you're expecting.
But after that, it always goes to second clause, and there is no chance to update the `sid` state variable